# How to set install time SQL queries

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, installation, windows-installer

Alright so this might be a trivial question but I couldn't find anything regarding the title.
I've made this application for a store which uses a database named Store with some tables named Dealers, Orders, Sales and a view named DetailedRecord. What I want is, when this application is being installed on the client machine, the relevant SQL queries be run to make those tables and views on the client machine.
I need a step by step method to do this, any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Please take a back up and restore it to client machine. While taking backup specify only scheme not the data...

Comment: Is there a way to direct the installshieldwizard to restore that backup?

Comment: SQL is a language, implemented to a greater or lesser extent by various database products. If you need to install your database, we need to know *which* product you're working with e.g. Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.

Comment: Yes, You can right click on database, then you can take a backup.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever SQL SERVER is the product

Comment: @AmitAgrawal No, I wanted to say while making installer for the application you basically add files to the package but is their a directive that makes the installer restore the database backed up?

Answer (score 0):

Once SQL Server is installed you can run a restore on the command line using SQLCMD.EXE. Here are some examples: http://www.howtogeek.com/50295/backup-your-sql-server-database-from-the-command-line/

So if you can call a command line from the installer, that's what you do.

I daresay just running object creation scripts might be simpler (and more modular) than restoring a backup. There are many editions of SQL Server, one of the ones at this link might be of use:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/hh230763.aspx